# Drop table and write new from Pandas to Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have some problem with writing dataframe to postgres table.

What I need to do is next: I need to save pandas df as Postgres table and tomorrow when new pandas df is created (can have more or fewer columns than df from the previous day) I need to delete Postgres table saved yesterday and write today's table in Postgres. Because of non-consistent number of columns, I can't write any DDL for the table.

What I have tried is next:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *


conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=passforpostgre")
cur = conn.cursor()
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://passforpostgre@localhost')

df = pd.DataFrame([['user1','adress1'], ['user2','adress2'], ['user3','adress3']], columns=["name", "address"])

df.to_sql('test_table', con=engine, if_exists='append')
sqlalchemy.delete('df3')
# cur.execute('DROP TABLE "%s";' % 'test_table')
```

And then I drop one columns (as I maybe will have another day)

```
df2.drop('address', 1)
d2.to_sql('test_table', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

But it doesn't matter if I use delete or DROP TABLE, a table is not deleted from the schema.  But I can't open it, it's just querying for a long time...

Can someone suggest me the most appropriate way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please re-phrase the problem and include desired result. Is this a Pandas' `to_sql`  problem or a Postgres' `DROP TABLE` or `SELECT` long query problem?

Comment: @Parfait The problem is drop table, but later on I figure that type of connection was a problem. Actually, I just to drop existed table and write new. But when I use code in my question, table is not deleted but also cannot be opened.

Comment: Please show the *actual* lines that cause the problem(s) and not the code that actually works.